# Support Vector Regression multiple outputs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am currently testing Support Vector Regression (SVR) for a regression problem with two outputs. This means that `Y_train_data` has two values for each sample. Since SVR can only produce a single output, I use the MultiOutputRegressor from [scikit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html).

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

    svr_reg = MultiOutputRegressor(SVR(kernel=_kernel, C=_C, gamma=_gamma, degree=_degree, coef0=_coef0))
    svr_reg.fit(X_train_data, Y_train_data)
```

Now I have noticed that even after hyperparameter optimization, SVR delivers significantly worse results than single decision trees.

Is this a known problem when using SVR with multiple outputs?

And would it better to create two seperate SVR models with different hyperparameters?

Comment: MultiOutputRegressor will not take the correlation between the target outputs into consideration. It will train a separate SVR for each output whereas Decision Trees can inherently handle multiple classes and hence may perform better

Comment: Did you normalize the features before applying SVR?

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments by Vivek Kumar your SVR might perform worse, because it does not calculate outputs simultaneously to take correlations between outputs into account. Hence I would propose to use an adapted SVR regression that is able to handle multiple targets such as Multiple-output Support Vector Regression. You can find an implementation [here](https://github.com/Analytics-for-Forecasting/msvr). You can then compare the results with your output from `MultiOutputRegressor` to check for improvements.